# Select and count street pattern features (morphology) using ArcGIS for Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, spatial-database, topology, cul-de-sac

I'd like to be able to select and count the number of cul-de-sacs, lollipops, dead ends, or other types of street structure in a hillside community.

Answer (score 4):

I'm going to make a few assumptions about your data:

1. Your roads are in one polyline feature class
2. Your roads are topologically correct (lines touch at intersections)

If so, you can create a topology and add a rule for "dangles".  This will analyse your data for roads that do not touch other roads (i.e. cul-de-sacs, etc).

Here are some links on topologies:

- [**Overview of Topology Toolset**](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#/An_overview_of_the_Topology_toolset/0017000000nn000000/)
- [**Topology Basics**](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//006200000002000000)
- [**Designing a Geodatabase Topology**](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//006200000004000000)

You can then validate the topology and it will highlight dangles.  You should be able to count these easily and limit them to your area of interest.

**EDIT:**

Thanks @Michael Miles-Stimson for the link to the tool to [**export topology errors**](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//00170000015w000000).

Comment: There is a tool Export Topology Errors http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//00170000015w000000 that will export the dangles/self intersections to a point feature class making for easier counting and/or Select by Location. The output includes a description of the 'rule that is broken' to help separate dangles and self intersections.

Comment: +1, but note this solution requires a Standard or Advanced license, and is not available at Basic.

Comment: Good point @ChrisW. That should be amongst my list of assumptions.  There's much missing from the OP's question.